# Update a UWP DataGrid style for single cell

Tags: uwp

I have a UWP DataGrid and want to set the cell style in C# for the selected row and cell that was edited in the CellEditEnded event. So far I can only set the column style for every row in the DataGrid.

```
Style style = new Style();
style.TargetType = typeof(DataGridCell);
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red)));
e.Column.CellStyle = style;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using applies the cell style to the entire column. Currently, you can't directly get the cell container so it is not possible to directly change the cell container.

A workaround for your scenario is that we are able to get the content in the specific cell. For example, the default content of a DataGrid is a TextBlock. Then you could change its foreground.

```
 private void dataGrid1_CellEditEnded(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Style style = new Style();
        //style.TargetType = typeof(DataGridCell);
        //style.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red)));
        //e.Column.CellStyle = style;

        TextBlock d = e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row) as TextBlock;
        d.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
        
    }
```